Kernel Oops GDB Backtrace Debug Help
I am running kernel 6.1 on ARM zynq7.
I have written some external kernel modules which i think are causing some kernel Oops but i can figure out where.
So i ran GDB via serial connection.
This is what i get but i am not sure how to interpret this.
Continuing.
[New Thread 706]
[New Thread 707]
[New Thread 708]

Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
rb_add_cached (less=<optimized out>, tree=0xef7d3014, node=0xef7d3320) at ./include/linux/rbtree.h:177
177             link = &parent->rb_right;
(gdb) bt 15
#0  rb_add_cached (less=<optimized out>, tree=0xef7d3014, node=0xef7d3320) at ./include/linux/rbtree.h:177
#1  timerqueue_add (head=0xef7d3014, head@entry=0x1, node=node@entry=0xef7d3320) at lib/timerqueue.c:40
#2  0xc0189570 in enqueue_hrtimer (mode=HRTIMER_MODE_ABS, base=<optimized out>, timer=0xef7d3320) at kernel/time/hrtimer.c:1091
#3  __run_hrtimer (now=<synthetic pointer>, flags=<optimized out>, timer=0xef7d3320, base=0xef7d3000, cpu_base=<optimized out>) at kernel/time/hrtimer.c:1702
#4  __hrtimer_run_queues (cpu_base=cpu_base@entry=0xef7d2fc0, now=<optimized out>, flags=flags@entry=536936851, active_mask=active_mask@entry=15)
    at kernel/time/hrtimer.c:1749
#5  0xc0189d78 in hrtimer_interrupt (dev=<optimized out>) at kernel/time/hrtimer.c:1811
#6  0xc010d454 in twd_handler (irq=<optimized out>, dev_id=<optimized out>) at arch/arm/kernel/smp_twd.c:185
#7  0xc016dd94 in handle_percpu_devid_irq (desc=0xc1018600) at kernel/irq/chip.c:930
#8  0xc01685d0 in generic_handle_irq_desc (desc=<optimized out>) at ./include/linux/irqdesc.h:158
#9  handle_irq_desc (desc=<optimized out>) at kernel/irq/irqdesc.c:646
#10 generic_handle_domain_irq (domain=<optimized out>, hwirq=<optimized out>) at kernel/irq/irqdesc.c:702
#11 0xc0401f10 in gic_handle_irq (regs=<optimized out>) at drivers/irqchip/irq-gic.c:372
#12 0xc08c87e8 in generic_handle_arch_irq (regs=0xc0e01ec8) at kernel/irq/handle.c:242
#13 0xc0100ba8 in __irq_svc () at arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S:221
#14 0xc0100ba8 in __irq_svc () at arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S:221
(More stack frames follow...)

None of my modules use high res timers.
I do have a module that uses IRQ from FPGA.
My question is how can i tell what is complaining/casuing the seg fault? Is it the first call rb_add_cached ?
I currently cant exactly reproduce the error other than letting the modules run for 10s of seconds. Basically its getting packet data and sending it to mac80211 via a custom driver.

Yes, the fault is coming in rb_add_cached, which is probably adding something to a red/black tree. My guess is it is a periodic timer adding itself back for future execution as this looks to be servicing a timer interrupt. As with all C programming this could just be memory corruption - use after free or accessing outside array bounds, and nothing to do with the timer code at all. ....

... if I was working on this the next command would be info registers and see exactly what instruction caused the exception, from this figure out what data structure was corrupt. Then examine the corruption to see if it suggests a cause. If possible I might alter the driver to add additional information to any data structures used by the custom driver, for example adding a char[20] at the start and end of any important structs and filling them with text to say what they are. This kind of work is not easy - assign your luckiest engineer to the problem.

thanks icarus, yes it turns out it was corruption. some code modifying skb was wrong which caused seemingly random error I'm gdb.  I removed that code and it's all good.

Glad that you were lucky enough to find the issue.
